# iptables rejecting localhost connection

Tags: centos, iptables

`iptables` is rejecting connection on localhost and i can't find what's causing it. I was given a centos 7 server to configure for a project and it had about 500 rules configured now after running my service on port `18081` i am getting

```
[amir@serverhXJopV70D1 ~]$ curl -v http://127.0.0.1:18081
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:18081...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 18081 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:18081
> User-Agent: curl/7.70.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Even though when i try to connect to the service via server's IP address everything is fine.

Followed this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10159/350376) in order to figure out which rule is causing the issue but the result is still incomprehensible to me

```
[amir@serverhXJopV70D1 ~]$ sudo iptables -L -v -n > Sample1 && curl 127.0.0.1:18081; sudo iptables -L -v -n > Sample2 && diff Samp*
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
14,16c14,16
< 28665 8728K LOCALINPUT  all  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
<  4321  256K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
< 27722 8645K INVALID    tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
---
> 28668 8728K LOCALINPUT  all  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>  4329  256K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
> 27725 8645K INVALID    tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
20c20
< 23598 8470K ACCEPT     all  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
---
> 23601 8470K ACCEPT     all  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
87c87
< 18511   10M LOCALOUTPUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
---
> 18516   10M LOCALOUTPUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
92,94c92,94
< 22969   10M SMTPOUTPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
<  4629  277K ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
< 17545 9985K INVALID    tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
---
> 22982   10M SMTPOUTPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>  4637  277K ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
> 17550 9986K INVALID    tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
96c96
< 17770   10M ACCEPT     all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
---
> 17773   10M ACCEPT     all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
117c117
<    33  2113 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
---
>    35  2233 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
342,343c342,343
< 28665 8728K ALLOWIN    all  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
< 28665 8728K DENYIN     all  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
---
> 28668 8728K ALLOWIN    all  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
> 28668 8728K DENYIN     all  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
347,348c347,348
< 18511   10M ALLOWOUT   all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
< 18511   10M DENYOUT    all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
---
> 18516   10M ALLOWOUT   all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
> 18516   10M DENYOUT    all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
379c379
<    32  1920 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x17/0x02 limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG flags 8 level 4 prefix "Firewall: *TCP_OUT Blocked* "
---
>    34  2040 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x17/0x02 limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG flags 8 level 4 prefix "Firewall: *TCP_OUT Blocked* "
382c382
<    33  2113 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
---
>    35  2233 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

[my question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63958576/4626485) explaining more about the service. at first i thought docker was causing the issue

UPDATE:
output of `sudo iptables -L -n  | grep tcp | grep -v ACCEPT`

```
INVALID    tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
INVALID    tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DROP       tcp  --  193.169.254.105      0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25
DROP       tcp  --  193.169.254.105      0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:465
DROP       tcp  --  193.169.254.105      0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:587
LOGDROPOUT  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            193.169.254.105      tcp dpt:25
LOGDROPOUT  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            193.169.254.105      tcp dpt:465
LOGDROPOUT  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            193.169.254.105      tcp dpt:587
INVDROP    tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x00
INVDROP    tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x3F
INVDROP    tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x03/0x03
INVDROP    tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x06/0x06
INVDROP    tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x05/0x05
INVDROP    tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x11/0x01
INVDROP    tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x18/0x08
INVDROP    tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x30/0x20
INVDROP    tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 ctstate NEW
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:23
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:68
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:111
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:113
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpts:135:139
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:500
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:513
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:520
LOG        tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* "
LOG        tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x17/0x02 limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG flags 8 level 4 prefix "Firewall: *TCP_OUT Blocked* "
LOGDROPOUT  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465,587
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
```

Comment: It might be more useful to post the output of `iptables -L -n ` in your question.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I could add it but since there are like 500 rules i don't think anyone would bother reading through it..  i will narrow it down to tcp connections that aren't `ACCEPT`

Comment: That's reset by peer, it looks more like a SELinux problem than iptables.

Comment: @tetech SELinux is disabled